# Admob Ads on Android App in Amazon

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, amazon-appstore

I have my app built for google play. It uses the Ads from Admob which is facilitated by the module from google play services. I hope that the google play services in not allowed in Amazon store.  Please advice if this can be used in the APK generated for Amazon store.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the google play services can be used on the amazon appstore no problems.
However, keep in mind that to update the ads integration in the future you will need to upgrade the SDK manually.

[This question](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/18240/admob-ads-with-google-play-service-sdk.html) is very similar to yours, and I am sure that forum will prove useful when releasing your app on the amazon appstore

If you are new to integrating aps I would also recommend researching a bit on ad mediation companies like Appodeal, MoPub, and others that will help make the integration easy and boost your earnings.

Best of luck with your app, and hope my answer proves useful!